# What is the interest of <functional> function objects in C++03?

Tags: c++, callback, functional-programming

I'm writing a wrapper around an http server in C++. My compiler only support C++03 (gcc 4.1.2) and I can't use boost.

I wanted to implement a generalized callback mechanism to answer the requests, able to register either a function or an object method or a static object method.

A (too) quick glance on `<functional>` function objects (C++03, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/) make me think that it was the answer.

However, it seems that `<functional>` function objects are not meant to provide a generalized callback mechanism.

So I wonder : what is the use of `<functional>` function objects in C++03 ? What are they meant for ? What true benefits are they supposed to provide over simple functions pointers ? Or is the C++03 version flawed and only the C++11 version is actually useful ?

[edit] For what I had understood at first, it seemed to me that a C++03 function object was just a useless wrapping over a function pointer. I'd rather use the function pointer directly, then. Correcting this wrong analysis is the point of this question !

Comment: Why can't you bind an object method with arguments?

Comment: @chris because the API doesn't allow it : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/mem_fun/

Comment: You can always use `std::function` and bind whatever you want to it.

Comment: @Offirmo: `std::bind`... ?

Comment: @chris I can't see `std::function` in the doc : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/

Comment: [Use a better reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) -- despite the name, cplusplus.com is not any kind of official C++ website.  Neither is the site I linked to, but it is more thorough.

Comment: Well, cplusplus.com sucks, so eh. Use http://cppreference.org, it includes the C++11 stuff.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using (the one you say works for simple functions)? I think I don't really understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Anyway, I have no C++11 (gcc 4.1.2)

Comment: Then use [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/function.html)

Comment: And anyway, thank you all but the question is not about my poor callback competency (edited the question to remove confusing stuff) but about the interest of `<functional>`. What are we supposed to achieve with it ?

Comment: @Offirmo functional gives you the opposite of function pointers: not function pointers. Seriously, have you seen their syntax?

Comment: @ta.speot.is but what is the use for those function objects ? They are used like a function pointer and utilities that accept them (like `transform()`) also accept a raw function pointer...

Comment: @Offirmo, That header has a lot more than `mem_fn`. `std::function` is useful for holding function pointers, lambdas, bind expressions and functors. There are also things like `std::bind`, `std::ref`, `std::reference_wrapper`, and all of the functors for operators, like `std::less`.

Comment: You are supposed to achieve more general, robust and easy to maintain code. Function objects are generalized and polymorphic, which makes generalized callbacks extremely easy to implement.

Comment: @chris it seems that the features you describe are recent additions (hence the discrepencies between the cplusplus.com and cppreference.com) so does it mean that the old `<functional>` was flawed ?

Comment: @Offirmo, Not really. Even those functors for operators are widely useful, and used in many of the algorithms as default values.

Comment: @chris useful how ? Useful for what ? That is precisely the question ;)

Comment: Actually, if you specify in your question that you are talking about C++03, and not C++11 `<functional>`, things might be clearer.

Comment: @Offirmo, `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::greater<vec.value_type>());`

Comment: @juanchopanza you are right, edited the question to restrict the scope.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your question, `<functional>` is a header, not a mechanism.  The header provides utilities for making function objects conveniently.  As a simple example, let's say you wanted to call transform, multiplying the elements of one range by another, and storing the result in a third.  You could define a function like this:

```
double mult(double lhs, double rhs) { return lhs * rhs; };
```

Then call it like this:

```
std::transform(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), out.begin(), mult);
```

Or you could use `std::multiplies`, which is already defined for you:

```
std::transform(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), out.begin(), std::multiplies<double>());
```

There are many other examples.  You just need to be creative.  C++11 lambdas have made many of the facilities in `<functional>` obsolete, or at least a lot less useful, because you can just define your functions inline with your algorithm calls.

> I wanted to implement a generalized callback mechanism to answer the
>   request

The C++03 version of `<functional>` does not help you with this.  The C++11 version does, with `std::function`, adapted from `boost::function`.

Comment: *you can just define your functions inline with your algorithm calls* Which, like almost everything, is not necessarily a good thing.

Comment: In the first example, I can't see where `<functional>` is needed, but in second example, it would mean that `<functional>` can work with a template function ? Then yes, that would be an improvement over simple function pointers.

Comment: @Offirmo: `<functional>` is not needed, period.  You can define all your functions out of line, as was done in the first example.  `<functional>` (the C++03 version) just provides several convenient functors so that you don't have to.

Comment: @Offirmo, It's the `operator()` for a template class.

Comment: @Offirmo: *"it would mean that <functional> can work with a template function ?"* -- I don't know what you mean by this. You keep referring to `<functional>` as if it is some kind of object or class or mechanism that you use. It's not that, it's a header.  You include it, and with it come several utilities.  So which utility are you referring to when you say it can work with a template function?  And what do you mean exactly by "work with a template function"?  Because function pointers also "work with template functions".

Comment: @BenjaminLindley you are right, edited the question to restrict the scope.

Comment: @Offirmo: Okay, but if I haven't answered your question, I still don't know what you're asking.  If the question is, *"What is the purpose of the facilities provided by the <functional> header?"*, then the answer is, simply, *"To provide some functions/functors to be used as callbacks, so you don't have to write them yourself"*.  Or, more generally *"To save you some typing"*, as is the case with any other library.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The rephrased question is : what is the interest of the function objects provided by `<functional>` ? Since for what I have seen, function objects are just a useless wrapping over function pointers. I'd rather use the function pointers directly, then. It seems that one interest could be when I don't have a function pointer in the first place, like with inline functions or template functions.

Comment: @Offirmo: Yes, that.  And for functions that cannot be otherwise named, or are hard to name, like operators.  Or for making minor modifications to functions, like inverting a predicate.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That it very interesting ! If you are kind enough to rephrase your answer and elaborate a bit, I will accept it. Your help is greatly appreciated !